# Move everything from one server to another

Tags: server, ubuntu-14.04, mean-stack, digital-ocean, baidu

I have a DigitalOcean & nginx server with IP address `xxx.xx.xx.xx` for several years. It has Ubuntu 14.04x64.

I just bought a Baidu server with IP address `yyy.yy.yy.yy`, it has Ubuntu 14.04x64 as well.

Now, I can connect to both servers by `ssh`.

I want to move the entire content of the DigitalOcean server to the Baidu server (without messing up the IP address of cause), does anyone know if there is any easy way to do that?

If not, one important website I want to move is built by `mean-stack`, is there an easy way to just move this website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scp` to send files between servers:

```
$ scp user@server1:/source/folder user@server2:/place/to/put
```

To learn more, check `man scp`

You can also use `rsync` :

```
$ rsync -avz user@server1:/source/folder user@server2:/place/to/put
```

For more info about rsync: 
 https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rsync.htm